# How do docker containers scale in Google App Engine?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

Google App Engine flexible allows you to deploy docker containers... how does scaling manifest itself?

- Will a new VM be spun up each time the application needs to scale or can it spin up new container instances on an existing VM?
- Can individual containers scale independent of each other? e.g. product container is under load but customer is not so only a new product container is spun up?

I realize GKE would be a better option for scaling containers, but I need to understand how this works on GAE for a multitude of reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- App Engine flex will only run one of your app container per VM instance. If it needs to scale up, it'll always create a new VM to run the new container.
- As per your example, if you want to scale "product" and "customer" containers separately, you'll need to define them as separate App Engine services. Each service will have its own scaling set up and act independently.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine is a [fully managed serverless platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/), where you basically submit a code and GAE will manage the underlying infrastructure and the runtime environment (for example the version of a python interpreter). You can also customize the runtime environment with Dockerfiles.

In contrast, **GKE** provides more fine-grained control on your cluster infrastructure. You can configure your computer resources, network, security, how the services are exposed, custom scaling policies, etc. GKE can be considered a managed container orchestration plaform.
An alternative to GKE that can provide even more control is creating the resources you need in **GCE** and configuring Kubernetes by yourself.

Both GKE and GAE are based and priced on compute engine instances. **Google Cloud Functions**, however, is a more recent [event-driven serverless service](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). GCF is great if you want to execute code on an event-driven basis (for example, sending a confirmation email after a user registers).

In terms of complexity and control over your code's environment I would order the different Google services as:
GCE(Compute Engine) > GKE(Kubernetes Engine) > GAE(App Engine) > GCF(Cloud Functions)

One point to consider is that the more low-level you go the easier it is to migrate your service to another platform.
Given that you seem to be deploying only containerized applications, I would recommend giving GKE a try, specially if you want to have a cluster of multiple services that interact with each other.

In terms of scaling, GAE will scale only VM instances and you have only one app per VM instance.
In GKE you have two types of scaling: container scaling and VM instance scaling. You can have multiple containers in one instance and those containers can be different apps. Based on limits you define (such as the CPU used in an app) GKE will try to efficiently allocate the containers across the instances of your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have containers, you can have a look to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/), which scale to 0 and can scale up very quickly (there is no new VM to proviion, that can take several seconds on AppEngine Flex).

However, long run aren't supported (limited to 15 minutes). All depends you requirement in term of feature, portability, scalability.

Provide more details if you want more advices.